# Authenticate with ADAL from Angular without redirecting to Microsoft login portal

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, angular7, adal

I have implemented authentication in my Angular 7 app against Azure AD by using the package [ng2-adal](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal). It works, but it redirects the user to the Microsoft online login page. The ideal scenario would be to allow users to enter credentials from my own login page and then perform some AJAX call to authenticate in the background. ¿Can this be done?

I have seen that this was impossible in the past, as the user could only customize the Microsoft login page to reflect some branding. I use ng2-adal becuase I haven't found many more options, but I am open to use another if possible.

Comment: What is the reason to do that? just the login page? 
You should know that if the organization has Office365 for example, you can have SSO in this way. When redirects to MS login page, automatically logs in and send you back to your website. And that is a great advantage for the users, they dont need to log in all the time.
I am not sure but i would bet that there is no chance to do what you are asking for. There is no reason to do it and is not secure, there is no reason to enter MS credentials outside MS. OAuth login is a good way to go...

Comment: this should be possible with the use of a service principle, although I don't know the exact details.

Comment: @Mikel Yes, my app automatically redirects to my website after the login, but that is not the point. I didn't found it relevant to say, but my app is a Cordova one, so it feels akward for the user to be redirected to a website from a mobile app.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the resource owner flow and password grant *if* you are using your own Azure AD tenant, although it is generally considered bad practice for your app to handle credentials at all.  Note that this would only work for users that are members of the AAD tenant.  It would break if the user needed to be redirected for a federated sign-on, a prompt for consent, or anything else that requires the user to interact with the IdP.  Also note that lots of failed password attempts can cause an IP address to be blocked (to prevent attacks), so you won't want to do this server-side with a static IP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc